# Copy of document created through DriveApp is not accessible through DocumentApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-apps

The below Google script is failing with error -

> Document is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)

on line `var body = DocumentApp.openById(NewdocumentId).getBody();` of the code below.

I am running the code from same account/script the new document copy is getting generated and then trying to access it the error occurs, what am I missing here???

```
  //Copy the template to new folder
  var NewdocumentId = DriveApp.getFileById('MyValidDocIDHere').makeCopy().getId();
  DriveApp.getFileById(NewdocumentId).setName(row_no + '_' + customer.checkout+ '_' + customer.name + '_' + customer.room);
  Utilities.sleep(9000);
  var body = DocumentApp.openById(NewdocumentId).getBody();
  body.replaceText("##DATE##", customer.checkin);
  NewdocumentId.saveAndClose();
```

Comment: Do you have access to `'MyValidDocIDHere'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, as this was a Google Sheet `SpreadsheetApp.openById` was to be used and not `DocumentApp.openById`, some old examples on the internet made me copy this mistake over :(